# getting the email value from the database and sending it (PHP email) / refresh page without the website link being changed

Tags: javascript, php, email, html-email

I Have 2 problems with this script, something is wrong
1. the email address value can't be selected from the database.
the script works only if I manually type the e-mail

```
$yourEmail = "email@exemple.com";
```

2. after I press the submit button, I want the page to refresh without the website link being changed or after i click send, the contact box should close.
   Could you please help to solve these problems?
   Thank you in advance!

   ```
           <?php
           $sql = "select * from tables where email='" . $email . "'";
           while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
           {
           $email=$row['email'];
           }
           $yourEmail = $email; // the email address you wish to receive these mails through
           $yourWebsite = "WEBSITE NAME";
           $thanksPage = ''; // URL to 'thanks for sending mail' page; leave empty to keep                          message on the same page 
           $maxPoints = 4; 
           $requiredFields = "name,email,comments";



           $error_msg = array();
           $result = null;

           $requiredFields = explode(",", $requiredFields);

           function clean($data) {
               $data = trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($data)));
               return $data;
           }
           function isBot() {
               $bots = array("Indy", "Blaiz", "Java", "libwww-perl", "Python", "OutfoxBot", "User-Agent", "PycURL", "AlphaServer", "T8Abot", "Syntryx", "WinHttp", "WebBandit", "nicebot", "Teoma", "alexa", "froogle", "inktomi", "looksmart", "URL_Spider_SQL", "Firefly", "NationalDirectory", "Ask Jeeves", "TECNOSEEK", "InfoSeek", "WebFindBot", "girafabot", "crawler", "www.galaxy.com", "Googlebot", "Scooter", "Slurp", "appie", "FAST", "WebBug", "Spade", "ZyBorg", "rabaz");

               foreach ($bots as $bot)
                   if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $bot) !== false)
                       return true;

               if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == " ")
                   return true;

               return false;
           }

           if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
               if (isBot() !== false)
                   $error_msg[] = "No bots please! UA reported as: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

               // lets check a few things - not enough to trigger an error on their own, but worth assigning a spam score.. 
               // score quickly adds up therefore allowing genuine users with 'accidental' score through but cutting out real spam :)
               $points = (int)0;

               $badwords = array("adult", "beastial", "bestial", "blowjob", "clit", "cum", "cunilingus", "cunillingus", "cunnilingus", "cunt", "ejaculate", "fag", "felatio", "fellatio", "fuck", "fuk", "fuks", "gangbang", "gangbanged", "gangbangs", "hotsex", "hardcode", "jism", "jiz", "orgasim", "orgasims", "orgasm", "orgasms", "phonesex", "phuk", "phuq", "pussies", "pussy", "spunk", "xxx", "viagra", "phentermine", "tramadol", "adipex", "advai", "alprazolam", "ambien", "ambian", "amoxicillin", "antivert", "blackjack", "backgammon", "texas", "holdem", "poker", "carisoprodol", "ciara", "ciprofloxacin", "debt", "dating", "porn", "link=", "voyeur", "content-type", "bcc:", "cc:", "document.cookie", "onclick", "onload", "javascript");

               foreach ($badwords as $word)
                   if (
                       strpos(strtolower($_POST['comments']), $word) !== false || 
                       strpos(strtolower($_POST['name']), $word) !== false
                   )
                       $points += 2;

               if (strpos($_POST['comments'], "http://") !== false || strpos($_POST['comments'], "www.") !== false)
                   $points += 2;
               if (isset($_POST['nojs']))
                   $points += 1;
               if (preg_match("/(<.*>)/i", $_POST['comments']))
                   $points += 2;
               if (strlen($_POST['name']) < 3)
                   $points += 1;
               if (strlen($_POST['comments']) < 15 || strlen($_POST['comments'] > 1500))
                   $points += 2;
               if (preg_match("/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]{7,}/i", $_POST['comments']))
                   $points += 1;
               // end score assignments

               foreach($requiredFields as $field) {
                   trim($_POST[$field]);

                   if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || empty($_POST[$field]) && array_pop($error_msg) != "Please fill in all the required fields and submit again.\r\n")
                       $error_msg[] = "Please fill in all the required fields and submit again.";
               }

               if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-'\s]*$/", stripslashes($_POST['name'])))
                   $error_msg[] = "The name field must not contain special characters.\r\n";
               if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i', strtolower($_POST['email'])))
                   $error_msg[] = "That is not a valid e-mail address.\r\n";
               if (!empty($_POST['url']) && !preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(:(\d+))?\/?/i', $_POST['url']))
                   $error_msg[] = "Invalid website url.\r\n";

               if ($error_msg == NULL && $points <= $maxPoints) {
                   $subject = "Automatic Form Email";

                   $message = "You received this e-mail message through your website: \n\n";
                   foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
                       if (is_array($val)) {
                           foreach ($val as $subval) {
                               $message .= ucwords($key) . ": " . clean($subval) . "\r\n";
                           }
                       } else {
                           $message .= ucwords($key) . ": " . clean($val) . "\r\n";
                       }
                   }
                   $message .= "\r\n";
                   $message .= 'IP: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\r\n";
                   $message .= 'Browser: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\r\n";
                   $message .= 'Points: '.$points;

                   if (strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], "Win")) {
                       $headers   = "From: $yourEmail\r\n";
                   } else {
                       $headers   = "From: $yourWebsite <$yourEmail>\r\n"; 
                   }
                   $headers  .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}\r\n";

                   if (mail($yourEmail,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
                       if (!empty($thanksPage)) {
                           header("Location: $thanksPage");
                           exit;
                       } else {
                           $result = 'Your mail was successfully sent.';
                           $disable = true;
                       }
                   } else {
                       $error_msg[] = 'Your mail could not be sent this time. ['.$points.']';
                   }
               } else {
                   if (empty($error_msg))
                       $error_msg[] = 'Your mail looks too much like spam, and could not be sent this time. ['.$points.']';
               }
           }
           function get_data($var) {
               if (isset($_POST[$var]))
                   echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[$var]);
           }
           ?>
   ```

html form

```
<form action="<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>" method="post">
<noscript>
        <p><input type="hidden" name="nojs" id="nojs" /></p>
</noscript>
<p>
    <label for="name">Name: *</label> 
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php get_data("name"); ?>" /><br />

    <label for="email">E-mail: *</label> 
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php get_data("email"); ?>" /><br />

    <label for="url">Website URL:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php get_data("url"); ?>" /><br />

    <label for="location">Location:</label>
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<?php get_data("location"); ?>" /><br />

    <label for="comments">Comments: *</label>
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="20"><?php get_data("comments"); ?></textarea><br />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" <?php if (isset($disable) && $disable === true) echo ' disabled="disabled"'; ?> />
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your while loop your suppose to actually perform the query with mysql_query or mysqli_query in your case mysql_query.
Your other problem is your fetching the results as an array which is index based (0...) and your using a string to access it so you should call mysql_fetch_assoc which returns an associative array which can be accessed in your current implementation

```
 $sql = "select * from tables where email='" . $email . "'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);// this actually performs the query and returns the result to be fetched using mysql_fetch_array or it's other methods such as mysql_fetch_assoc
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $email=$row['email'];
 }
```

Also declare your $email variable outside the while loop as if no rows were returned from the database your $email variable won't exist therefore breaking your code so you should bring it to the top of the while loop and initialize it to some default value.

Comment: Yes, I tried, does not work, I think it is an internal script error.